# Best Method for Converting An Executable to A Word Doc?

Tags: file-conversion

I'm sorting through a bunch of old writings & am running across a large number of files, which are exe's rather than doc or docx or txt or any other normal text doc format. I am almost positive that all of these writings were done in Microsoft Word for Mac (probably) 2004. There are gibberish characters at the header & footers but the body text has all seemed intact, from what I've glanced at. I am curious about how this might have happened, but my priority right now is just reconverting these files back to a simple text format. There are hundreds of documents, mostly notes, but some finished pieces and I would much prefer to not have to go in & remove the junk text from all of them by hand. So...what are my options? thx

Comment: An exe file is not a document to be converted.  It's a *program executable* file; it's the actual program.  Word for Mac saved in doc format just like Word for Windows.

Comment: I know what an exe is. And I know the contents of these files are text, words arranged sequentially to tell stories, not code. Somehow they were converted to EXEs and I need to change them back.

Comment: Open it  in Word.  If Word can't read it, then you have an unknown format and its impossible for anyone to guess it without seeing it.

Comment: Compressed self extracting exe files?

Comment: Could you upload a representative file, to e.g. http://www.tinyupload.com, and provide the download URL, so we can get a better handle on your issue? That would be preferable however if not, then at the least, you need to run the following commands in a Terminal and add the output to your question. `file filename` where `filename` is the name of the file. In a Terminal type "file ", that's "file " followed by a space `file `, then drag & drop the file on the Terminal window and press enter. Then do, `cat filename | head -c 8 | xxd -p`. Continued in next comment...

Comment: In other words type type "cat ", `cat `, then drag & drop the file on the Terminal window, then type `| head -c 8 | xxd -p` and press enter. The `file` command should determine the file's type and output some info for it and the second command set with give the first 8 bytes in hex so we know what the header looks like. The bottom line is without being able to look at and examine the files and or having some concrete technical information about the files there is nothing definitive to act upon to try and help with the issue. Maybe do this with several files for comparison.

Comment: OK, the cat command tells me 'command not found'; 'file doesn't exist'...Foul Language Warning, but here is one of the problem files: https://file.io/1NQDGO Alan, opening in Word, it asks me to pick an encoding, none of which get rid of the gibberish, some of which allow the text to co-exist with the gibberish.

Comment: alt link: http://dropcanvas.com/ggdvd

Comment: @Kerlix, I was able to open the linked file, for proper display, in [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/), which by the way is free. Also the file is not an executable and if it's show as one it not properly enumerating its file type and or the execute bit is improperly set.

Answer (score 3):

The file you [linked](http://dropcanvas.com/ggdvd) can be opened, for proper display, in [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/), which by the way is free.

I was also able to convert this file via the command line to a plain text document using LibreOffice's executable `soffice` using the following syntax:

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to txt $FileNameToConvert
```

Example:

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to txt "'…& hitting number three on 3"
```

The above command created the "'…& hitting number three on 3.txt" file and I then opened it in TextEdit and it displayed properly as it should.

You can batch convert the documents in the same manner by using a wildcard (an asterisk), e.g..:

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to txt *
```

The above command to batch convert assumes you've installed LibreOffice in `/Applications` and placed the files to convert in their own directory and have changed to that directory in Terminal.

Note: If you want to convert the files to Microsoft Word documents use `doc` or `docx` instead of `txt` for the `--convert-to` option, e.g.: `--convert-to doc`

Comment: **Update Note:** The linked file is no longer available. From an archived copy I still have, based on the files signature in its header, it appears to be a AppleWorks 6 document.

Answer (score 1):

The command line utility `textutil` can do the job. The basic syntax would be

```
textutil -convert txt -- filename
```

To batch process a group of files in a folder the syntax would be

```
textutil -convert txt -- /path/to/folder/*
```

`textutil` can convert both .doc and docx files among other file formats.

Comment: Well, what's weird is Terminal tells me Done, that it's worked, but the files I've tried converting are still exe's and full of gobbeldygook

Comment: OK, the files aren't MS word documents. Your sample file reveals the magic number BOBO which is an AppleWorks document.